# First order hold from zero order hold filter

Tags: sampling, digital-to-analog, zoh

I'm stuck in this question for more than 4 hours. (h is the sampling period)

[image]

I simplified the block diagram but it just seems impossible to get the FOH transfer function from the reduced block diagram... Am I missing something?

My try:

[image]

Comment: What's h ? The sampling period?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: I think you're running into difficulty because this is a strange mix of continuous- and sample-time, and you're not dealing with the implicit sampling in the ZOH correctly.  Basically, there's no transfer function (that I know of) for sampling, because it's a time-varying process.  So think in the time domain.  Ask yourself, if the output of the ZOH is $a_{-1}$ in the interval $-h < t < 0$, what is the output of the integrator at time $t = 0^-$?  And if the incoming signal is $a_0 \delta(t)$ around $t=0$, what is the output of the ZOH at time $t = 0^+$?